# PySpark DataFrame reduce_by

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

My DataFrame `df` has a column acting as a foreign key to a table that's many-to-one with `df`. For each unique value of the foreign key, it contains another foreign key, but only once, with all over values in that group being empty :

```
df.filter(df.foreignkey1 == "12345").select("foreignkey1", "foreignkey2").show()

+-----------+-----------+
|foreignkey1|foreignkey2|
+-----------+-----------+
|      12345|           |
|      12345|           |
|      12345|           |
|      12345|  100002020|
|      12345|           |
+-----------+-----------+
```

Here, I've selected all entries where `foreignkey1` is 12345, and displayed the values of `foreignkey2` next to them.

I'd like to collapse this down to this :

```
+-----------+-----------+
|foreignkey1|foreignkey2|
+-----------+-----------+
|      12345|  100002020|
+-----------+-----------+
```

In theory, there should only be one `foreignkey2` per unique value of `foreignkey1`, although part of this is testing that.

I'm fairly new to Spark, and this seems like a good place to ask others, to ensure I follow "Spark thinking". Any help would be much appreciated. Is my best option `df.rdd.reduceByKey` or is there some more intelligent way to do this using groupby and aggregate functions ? Thanks !

Comment: Just thought : I could probably just `dropna()` and see if that's longer than the number of unique values in `foreignkey1`. However, that doesn't guarantee that there's one `foreignkey2` per `foreignkey1` - though it possibly strongly indicates it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could do the trick:

```
df.groupBy("fk").agg(max("fk2"))
```

It will return only two columns: `fk` and `max(fk2)`. The second column will have the largest value for `fk2` found for each value of `fk`.

However, this approach is not very efficient. So, alternatively, if you are sure there is only one value in `fk2` for each value in `fk` and you don't need other columns, maybe you can do the following:

```
df.select("fk", "fk2").filter(col("fk2").isNotNull())
```

Otherwise, if there can be more than one `fk2` per `fk`, you can try merging both approaches,  as an attempt to improve performance:

```
df.select("fk", "fk2").filter(col("fk2").isNotNull()).groupBy("fk").agg(max("fk2"))
```

Comment: 2nd approach is much better, if Daniel's assumptions are correct, from an efficiency perspective

Comment: Thanks, a good solution. In terms of checking that I have a one-to-one map between my FKs, the second snippet will be helpful : after having run it, I can compare the number of rows in this DF with the number of unique values of fk1.